# Computed property value not returned correctly from Vuex store on mounted/created hook

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**Scenario** 
I have a custom component which loads a calendar and a simple dropdown to set its time. Once the user sets the date and time these values are sent through the Vuex store. Once I have made sure these values are set correctly, I am trying to retrieve the data through a computed property `times` which should return an array of objects such as `[{start_time: "2020-08-12T01:00:00.000Z", end_time: "2020-08-12T02:00:00.000Z"}]` which is whatever the user has selected and subsequently stored in the store, however, for some reason I get an empty array on the mounted hook when I `console.log(this.times)`.

**Test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="settings-section" v-for="(t,idx) in times" :key="idx">
      <div class="date-time-cross" v-if="times.length > 1">
        <img width="20px" height="20px" src="~/assets/svgs/bin.svg" v-on:click="removeDate(idx)" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Event starts</span>
        <v-dtpicker
          :ref="`dtstart${idx}`"
          :value="t.start_time"
          @input="handleValueChange($event, idx, 'start_time')"
        />
        <span class="error-msg" v-show="!t.start_time && errors_['date']">This field is required.</span>
        <span
          class="error-msg"
          v-show="t.start_time > t.end_time"
        >The start time needs to be before the end of the event.</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Event ends</span>
        <v-dtpicker
          :ref="`dtend${idx}`"
          :value="t.end_time"
          @input="handleValueChange($event, idx, 'end_time')"
        />
        <span class="error-msg" v-show="!t.end_time && errors_['date']">This field is required.</span>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr-t" v-if="times.length > 1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VDtpicker from "~/components/v-datetime/v-dtpicker.vue";
import VTimepicker from "~/components/v-datetime/v-timepicker.vue";

export default {
  layout: "noFooter",

  data() {
    return {
      errors_: {
        name: null,
        host: null,
        address_string: null,
        venue: null,
        description: null,
        banner: null,
        date: null,
        recurrent_rule_weekday: null,
        recurrent_rule_time_start: null,
        recurrent_rule_time_end: null,
        recurrent_rule_from: null,
        recurrent_rule_until: null,
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    VDtpicker,
    VTimepicker,
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log("THE TIME IS:: ", this.times);
    if (this.times.length > 0) 
    this.dateSlots();
  },
  methods: {
    dateSlots() {
      this.$store.commit("timeDetails/addTime", {
        start_time: null,
        end_time: null,
      });
    },

    handleValueChange(time, idx, type) {
      switch (type) {
        case "start_time":
          this.$store.commit("timeDetails/updateTime", {
            value: time,
            field: "start_time",
            event_time_idx: idx,
          });
          break;

        case "end_time":
          this.$store.commit("timeDetails/updateTime", {
            value: time,
            field: "end_time",
            event_time_idx: idx,
          });

          break;
      }
    },
  },

  computed: {
    times: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.timeDetails.details.times;
      },

      set(value) {},
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**timeDetails.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    details: {
        times: []
    }
});

export const mutations = {
    addTime(state, time) {
        console.log('store - time received', time);
        state.details.times.push(time);
    },

    updateTime(state, time) {
        switch(time.field) {
            case 'start_time':
                state.details.times[time.event_time_idx][time.field] = time.value;
            break;

            case 'end_time':
                state.details.times[time.event_time_idx][time.field] = time.value;
            break;
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: You're initialising `times` to `[]`, then `mounted` is run and logs `[]` and only then the user can select a date. What am I missing? Where are you updating `times` before `mounted` is run?

Comment: Well isn’t the computed property running before the mounted hook? Times should update via the computed property by retrieving the data from the store.

Comment: But it looks like it will still be `[]` in the store. Or where are you updating its value?

Comment: On mounted I am checking the Array, and if it’s empty then I push into it via the dateSlots function. However, my question is, despite the array non being empty in my scenario why is the mounted hook printing out an empty array?

Comment: Probably because it is still empty. [Here](https://codepen.io/asdasgqq/pen/gOrYeKo) is an example where `mounted` gets the computed value.

Comment: Thank you for the example, however the problem arise when you add an else on the if statement, and you will see that despite the array's length being greater than 0, it does not go straight to the else condition.

Comment: Would you please create a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Check this out, please. https://jsfiddle.net/HeyabRedda/0p8o4krq/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219163/discussion-between-d-malan-and-heyred).